# WPF TextBox ConvertBack - what should i do with this?

Tags: wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

So i have `ListViewItem` with `TextBox` and `ComboBox`.

Inside my `ComboBox` i have several options and once my `ComboBox` selected change `event` fired in my Model i have changed my property:

```
public int ComboboxSelectedIndex
{
    get { return _comboboxSelectedIndex; }
    set
    {
        _comboboxSelectedIndex = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

In my `TextBox` i have this `Converter` and once my `ComboBox` selected change `event` fired i want my `TextBox` to be cleared:

```
<TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="False"
         TextChanged="textboxOldValueCell_TextChanged"                                
         LostFocus="textboxOldValueCell_LostFocus"                                                                                                                               
         Text="{Binding ComboboxSelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource ComboboxSelectedIndexToTextBoxText}}"/>

public class ComboboxSelectedIndexToTextBoxText : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

    }
}
```

So this works fine until my `TextBox` lost focus and then i can see `Red` color around my `TextBox` border.
So my question is what i need to put at this `ConvertBack` function in order to clear my `TextBox` ?

Comment: Try to make the Binding OneWay.

Comment: OK that works thanks !